# How to solve these mongoDb query

Tags: mongodb-query

```
{
                    "_id": "SG01",
                    "name": "Pawan",
                    "marks": [
                        {
                            "English": 93,
                            "Maths": 90,
                            "Hindi": 89,
                            "Sci": 98
                        }
                    ],
                    "__v": 0
                }

  {
                    "_id": "SG02",
                    "name": "Dravid",
                    "marks": [
                        {
                            "English": 40,
                            "Maths": 67,
                            "Hindi": 56,
                            "Sci": 45
                        }
                    ],
                    "__v": 0
                }
  {
                    "_id": "SG03",
                    "name": "Kartik",
                    "marks": [
                        {
                            "English": 65,
                            "Maths": 77,
                            "Hindi": 80,
                            "Sci": 79
                        }
                    ],
                    "__v": 0
                }
```

I have been tried This Query

```
db.Student3.aggregate([{$unwind:{path:"$results"}},{$addFields:{HighestScores:{$max:["$results.score"]}}}])
```

But there is no result as per my expecting result.

I want Output like this.

| Student Name | Name of Subject of Highest Marks |
| --- | --- |
| Student 1 | English |
| Student 3 | Maths |

Comment: Are you sure the data you show is correct? You reference `$results` in your query twice, but the data has no `results` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $set: {
  marks: {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$marks",
      "as": "m",
      "in": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$m"
      }
    }
    }
  }
 },
 {
   $unwind: "$marks"
 },
 {
  $addFields: {
   marks: {
    $let: {
      vars: {
        maxk: {
          "$max": "$marks.v"
        }
      },
      in: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$marks",
          as: "m",
          cond: {
            "$eq": [
              "$$m.v",
              "$$maxk"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   $unwind: "$marks"
  },
  {
   $project: {
  _id: 0,
  name: 1,
  maxMark: "$marks.k"
    }
   }
 ])
```

Explained:

1. transform objects to array to be easier to get max value
2. unwind to flatten the array
3. filter only objects with max value
4. unwind to flatten the array with single element
5. project only the needed fields

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r3cn311HMol)

Comment: abit more optimal version removing the last $unwind: https://mongoplayground.net/p/oZACFN9Gwkg

Comment: btw , just realized that there is 1x object in every marks array per student , do you expect to have more objects per semester in this array? Or there is no need to be array since the current solution will give you the max Mark per object , but if you have more objects it needs to be different ?